# Is dot product defined for matrices for other than terms being $n \times 1$ or $1 \times n$ vectors?

Tags: matrices

Is dot product defined for matrices for other than terms being $n \times 1$ or $1 \times n$ vectors?

That is,

is $Ax\cdot b$ defined for other than $Ax\in M_{1 \times n} \text{ or } M_{n \times 1}$?

Comment: the dot product doesn't produce vectors it produces scalars.

Comment: @Thoth I mean "inside" the dot product. Like in $Ax \cdot b$ both $Ax$ and b are vectors.